# Iterating JavaScript object with strings as keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a JavaScript array, which has strings as keys.

The array should have an object at every entry. My object looks like this (a `console.log` of my variable `rIds`):

[image: Firebug screenshot of my variable]

Now, the length of this object is 0, which makes it impossible to iterate it.

I want to iterate every key, so I can retrieve and access my list of ids (`rIds[key].productIds`).

**Code**:

```
var rIds = [];
        var response = RR.data.JSON.placements;

        console.log(response);
        $(response).each(function (placementId) {
            var placement_name = this.placement_name;

            rIds[this.placement_name] = {
                productIds: []
            };

            $(this.recs).each(function (recIndex) {
                var pid = this.pid;
                pid = getRandomId(19341610, 19341746);
                rIds[placement_name].productIds[recIndex] = pid;
            });
        });

        var count = '<%=ViewBag.Get("RecommendationCount") %>';

        console.log(rIds);
        console.log(rIds.length);
        $.each(rIds, function (index, val) {
            console.log(val);  // This should work as expected.
        });
```

**What did I try?**

I found the following snippet, which does not work in IE8. However, this does not really help be, even though `Object.keys(rIds).length` results in the correct length.

```
for (var index = 0; index < Object.keys(rIds).length; index++) {
            console.log(rIds[index]);
        }
```

However, this code does not make my access the object.

**Tl;dr & question**

- How do I iterate my JavaScript object which has strings as keys, so I can access the individual entries?

Comment: perhaps a jsfiddle would aid potential answerer

Comment: A JavaScript object with (non-numeric) strings as keys is not an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Object.keys()` function returns an array containing the property names of the object.

```
var keys = Object.keys(rIds);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
  console.log(rids[keys[i]]); // object value
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `.forEach()` method:

```
Object.keys(rIds).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(this[key]);
}, rIds);
```

Finally there's the venerable `for ... in` loop:

```
for (var key in rIds) {
  if (rIds.hasOwnProperty(key))
    console.log(rIds[key]);
```

To support versions of IE before IE9 you're kind-of stuck with `for ... in`, though you can find mostly-correct "polyfills" for [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) at MDN.

Comment: OP did mention this, but doesn't work in IE8 - so worth mentioning the alternative too.

Comment: @RGraham yes thanks I was thinking incrementally :) I took my dog for a walk instead of guzzling coffee this morning so my brain is slow.

Comment: Lol! Good responsible pet ownership :)

Answer (score 1):

To supplement [Pointy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25385155/710446), you can also use jQuery's [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) (since you're already using jQuery elsewhere) to iterate over each key/value pair in your `rIds` object:

```
$.each(rIds, function(key, value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```